# Catching exceptions on fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to create a script using fabric API (not fab files) and can't get the exceptions to work. My idea is, once a host has failed, is to perhaps run a `rollback()` function and write a log file about the failed host. The thing is the system always exits. This is my code:

```
class FabricException(Exception):
    pass

class Main(object):

  def __init__(self):
    env.password = 'password'
    env.user = 'whatever'
    command = 'sudo ls -la'
    failed = []
    env.warn_only = True
    env.abort_exeption = FabricException

    def runCommand(command):
        try:
            result = run(command)
        except FabricExeption:
            print env.host + "failed"
            failed.append = env.host

    execute(runCommand, command=command, hosts=hosts)
    disconnect_all()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main = Main()
```

Comment: You are aware that all this code does is creating the class `FabricException` with a quite strange body‽

Comment: I have just edited. For some reason is getting some funny format when tried to add the Main class. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is logging this failure, why not use a context manager, and have the block of code only warn. Using either/both of these settings: `env.warn_only` and `env.skip_bad_hosts`.

refs:

- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#failure-handling
- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#skip-bad-hosts
- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#warn-only